# Match the character * and not the \* in regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string `Item * \* and *`. I would like to match the all the `*` characters and skip the `\*` one.

```
var input = "Item * \\* and *";
var output = (some regex magic happens here)
alert(output); // Item foo \* and foo
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What language/platform are you using? What have you tried so far? What should happen if your string contains `\\*`? All of these are vital parts of your question that are missing.

Comment: What language/platform are you using? **Javascript** What have you tried so far? **I was able to match the "*" but with the space only.** What should happen if your string contains `\\*`? **Shouldn't match it**

Comment: What precisely should the output be? An array like `["Item * ", " and *"]`? Please make your problem statement more clear.

Comment: I would like to replace the matched `*` with a text. I guess I can just use `text.replace(regex, "foo")`

Comment: replacing with what? post the expected output.

Comment: Output example `Item foo \* and foo`

Comment: here it is http://regex101.com/r/yI6dE1/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I think you're trying to acheive:

```js
var input = "Item * \\* and *"; 
var repl = "foo";
var output = input.replace(/(\\\*)|\*/g, function(_, a) { return a || repl; });
alert(output); // Item foo \* and foo
```

Basically, when you provide a function to the [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method, it will pass in the match and any matched groups as arguments to that function and use the return value as the replacement string. In this case, since the argument `a` only has a value when it matches `"\*"`, it will leave that match unmodified. Otherwise, it will replace it with `"foo"`.